# SQLite : DEFAULT values are not set to table's columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create a table in my app's SQLite database that has 3 columns that accept integer values. To create the table I use the following code :

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("HelpMeDatabase", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings (\n" +

                "\t whatsapp \t INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,\n" +
                "\t viber \t INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,\n" +
                "\t vibration \t INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1\n" +
                ");");
```

The table is created successfully but the default values are not assigned to the columns . Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: please remove all those `\t` and `\n`... and try uninstall and reinstall your app. I suppose you added the `DEFAULT`s **after** creating your table once. So, **it won't be created again**.

Comment: @ Der Gol...lum it did not work

Comment: ...Are you inserting any rows into the table?

Comment: Also, you may want to consider using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for your settings instead of a database. It's a much better fit for this use case.

Comment: @nkorth No . I just want this table to have a single row by default

Comment: You have to insert a row using an `INSERT` statement. It won't just automatically appear. The default values you specified are for *each new row*, fitting to the intended use of a database (which is storing many rows of structured data).

Comment: agreed with @nkorth ,must call INSERT statement to insert single row of data with default value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for taking too long to answer. Thanks to @nkorth's and @Rajesh Khadka's suggestions I managed to solve my issue.

So, after the table's creations I put this condition to Insert a single row just once.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings (" +

                " whatsapp  INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL," +
                " viber  INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL," +
                " vibration  INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL" +
                ");");

        if (isFirstTime()) {
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO settings VALUES (1,1,1)");
        }
```

**isFirstTime() :**

```
private boolean isFirstTime()
    {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
        if (!ranBefore) {
            // first time
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
            editor.commit();
        }
        return !ranBefore;
    }
```

This code makes sure Insert is only executed once.